# starting tomcat from jar file in ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, profiling

I am using tomcat for the first time. I have downloaded and unzipped tomcat 7.0.28. I am able to start and shutdown it form the command prompt by ./startup.sh and ./shutdown.sh. So far it works fine. I can see tomcat homepage and examples also in the browser.

But what I want is to profile tomcat server with java profiler. **For that I want to run it from jar file. Something like java -jar tomcat_allrequiredclasses.jar.** Is there any way I can start tomcat server like this ? I tried to run jar files of tomcat residing in bin directory but gave me classNotdefined exception(just to try i did that).

Thank you..

Comment: Attach with JVisualVM in the JDK instead.  This allows you to profile a running program without special invocation voodoo.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat needs a lot of system properties and things like that to be set at JVM launch, so the script is necessary unless you are going to use "embedded Tomcat" and write your own launch driver using [Tomcat's embedded driver](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html).

I think that's overkill for just attaching a profiler. Most profilers come with a JVM "agent" that you can configure to attach on JVM launch using the `-agentpath` command-line option. This is how I attach YourKit Java Profiler, for example:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-agentpath:/path/to/yourkit/libyjpagent.so=${yourkit.options}"
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

This will launch Tomcat in the usual way, but include the JVM profiler agent so you can then attach to it afterward.

***Update to include OP's example***

You want to do this:

```
$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:lib/jborat-agent.jar -Xss256m -Xms256m  \ -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.exclusionList="conf/exclusion.lst" \ -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.dumpers="ch.usi.dag.jp2.dump.xml.XmlDumper" \ -Xbootclasspath/p:./lib/Thread_JP2.jar:lib/jborat-runtime.jar:lib/jp2-runtime.ja‌​r"
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

I encourage you to use complete paths whenever possible (e.g. don't use `lib/jborat-agent.jar` -- add the full path).

Note that by using the `-Xss256M`, you are setting the *thread stack size* to 256M and not the heap size. I suspect you meant to use `-Xmx256M` to set the maximum size of the heap.

Comment: Hi Christopher, Thanks for your response. You are right my java profiler also contains JVM agent. I am running my profiler by script file say run.sh. which looks like: java -Xss256m -Xms256m -javaagent:lib/jborat-agent.jar \
 -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.exclusionList="conf/exclusion.lst" \
 -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.dumpers="ch.usi.dag.jp2.dump.xml.XmlDumper" \ -Xbootclasspath/p:./lib/Thread_JP2.jar:lib/jborat-runtime.jar:lib/jp2-runtime.jar $*  so if I want to run tomcat with this, could you please tell me what exactly should I include in my run.sh ?

Comment: You should stop using your own `run.sh` and instead use `bin/setenv.sh` (you may have to create this) containing your `export CATALINA_OPTS=...` line. Then, just launch `bin/startup.sh` and your system properties will be added to the JVM launch command. There really is no reason for your `run.sh` script to exist.