# Adding Profiler script in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling

I want to profile tomcat server with a java profiler. My profiler runs from the script say run.sh which looks like below:

```
if [ -z "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
   if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
      JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
   else
      JAVACMD="`which java`"
   fi
 fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
 echo "Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly; cannot execute: $JAVACMD"
 exit 1
fi


java  -javaagent:lib/jborat-agent.jar \
 -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.exclusionList="conf/exclusion.lst" \
  -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.liblist="conf/lib.lst" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.outputFilePrefix="output" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.instrumentation="ch.usi.dag.jp2.instrument.AddInstrumentation" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.dumpers="ch.usi.dag.jp2.dump.xml.XmlDumper" \
     -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.codemergerList="conf/codemerger.lst" \
      -Xbootclasspath/p:./lib/Thread_JP2.jar:lib/jborat-runtime.jar:lib/jp2-runtime.jar/jp2.jar/jborat-agent.jar/jborat.jar $*
```

Could somebody please guide me how can I include this profiler in tomcat ?

Is it possible to write something like this CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:run.sh" in catalina.sh ?

I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks.

I tried adding options of run.sh (profiler) to setenv.sh as below but does not work. It does not give any error but The server is not starting. I dont know why.

Here is my setenv.sh file:

```
 #!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="java -javaagent:lib/jborat-agent.jar \
 -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.exclusionList="conf/exclusion.lst" \
  -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.liblist="conf/lib.lst" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.outputFilePrefix="output" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.instrumentation="ch.usi.dag.jp2.instrument.AddInstrumentation" \
   -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.dumpers="ch.usi.dag.jp2.dump.xml.XmlDumper" \
     -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.codemergerList="conf/codemerger.lst" \
      -Xbootclasspath/p:./lib/Thread_JP2.jar:lib/jborat-runtime.jar:lib/jp2-runtime.jar/jp2.jar/jborat-agent.jar/jborat.jar "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered [your exact same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600545/starting-tomcat-from-jar-file-in-ubuntu#11600635). Briefly, you want this:

```
$ export CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:lib/jborat-agent.jar -Xss256m -Xms256m  \ -Dch.usi.dag.jborat.exclusionList="conf/exclusion.lst" \ -Dch.usi.dag.jp2.dumpers="ch.usi.dag.jp2.dump.xml.XmlDumper" \ -Xbootclasspath/p:./lib/Thread_JP2.jar:lib/jborat-runtime.jar:lib/jp2-runtime.ja‌​r"
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

I don't understand why you need more than that: your script just adds a bunch of system properties to the JVM launcher: you can do that with `$CATALINA_OPTS`. If you want to set them somewhat permanently, put the `export` into `bin/setenv.sh` and it will automatically be run every time you run `bin/startup.sh` (and `bin/shutdown.sh` for that matter).

Comment: Actually I thought I did not make myself clear in my previous question regarding using profiler with tomcat so asked it again. Sorry for that. I tried the way you said but does not work. It does not give error but profiler is not producing output. I think the reason is, in the profiler which I use, One has to give an argument(what you want to profile (class file or runnable jar file). In case of tomacat I dont know how to do that..I have to figure it out.

Comment: What profiler are you using? A Google search for "java borat profiler" yields nothing useful to me.

Comment: I am using jp2 profiler..You will not get it on google. It's official site is under construction. It is not widely used but it does exactly what I want.

Comment: If you can't configure it with system properties, then it does *not* do what you want. There's no reason you should have to launch the profiler from its own shell script. If you want to run Tomcat's `bin/startup.sh` and then check a process listing for the full command-line, you could probably replicate that if absolutely necessary. But it's a complete pain to do and you need to ask the profiler folks to get with the program and work like everybody else.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary for me to launch the profiler from script. As you told before my profiler just sets few system properties at the start up of JVM, I should be able to add it by CATALINA_OPTS or JAVA_OPTS. So what I tried is here: As you suggested I created setenv.sh file in bin dir of tomacat and wrote system properties need to be set by my profiler as CATALINA_OPTS. But after that when I try to start the server it does not give any error on console. but when I access localhost:8080 in browser it keeps on trying to connect. kind of infinite loop. any guess why so ? Thanks.

Comment: I want to ask you one more thing: As u see in my profiler run script in last line there is option of -Xbootclasspath which is used with java command. So where do you think I should write that xbootclasspath in Catalina.sh ?

Comment: Don't put anything in `catalina.sh`: but everything into `setenv.sh`. And use `CATALINA_OPTS`: you can set anything you want: it all gets put onto the command line that launches the JVM.

Comment: If Tomcat appears not to be responding, take a thread dump and find out what is going on in the JVM. If the profiler is in some kind of beta, maybe it's got some bug that is causing it to hand when the agent is started.

Comment: Could u please have a look on my setenv.sh file which I have added in my question here and give me an idea what may be wrong ? Thanks..

Comment: The first thing wrong @user523956 is that you have your quotes all messed-up: you need to escape all of the `"`" characters that appear within your outer `"` pair. The second problem is that you have the word "java" at the beginning of your `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable, and it does not belong there. `CATALINA_OPTS` is a list of options that will be passed to the JVM... there is no reason to put the "java" command into the options: it will probably cause the JVM to fail to start.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I changed the setenv.sh file as you specified and it works now.. I really appreciate your patience and help so far :-) Thanks a lot..It made my day !